# Physical object does not move with sprite

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

Using AndEngine, I want to move an object so I create a Sprite:

```
tower1 = new Sprite(50, 150, this.tower1TextureRegion,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
tower1Body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, tower1,
            BodyType.KinematicBody, towerFixtureDef);
this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(tower1,
            tower1Body, true, true));
```

and then define moving:

```
moveTower1 = new MoveXModifier(actualDuration, tower1.getX(), -150f)
     {
     @Override protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity 
     removeTower(tower1); }
     }; 
     tower1.registerEntityModifier(moveTower1);
```

When I run this app, the sprite is moving but the physical object isn't. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach a sprite to a body you can no longer move it with modifiers. The physics world essentially now owns it as regards to position, (i.e., if the body moves due to a force being applied, the connected sprite will move with it). You can move it only by appling forces to the body itself., i.e.,

```
tower1Body.applyLinearImpulse(impulseX, impulseY, pointX, pointY);
```

or,

```
tower1Body.applyForce(forceX, forceY, pointX, pointY);
```

Or a linear velocity,

```
tower1Body.setLinearVelocity(vX, vY);
```

Also be warned that the co ordinates in the physics world differ from those in your scene. For example tower1.getX() are the coordinates in your scene of sprite tower1 but in the physics world the position of the body will differ by /PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With box2d you need to move the body, not the sprite. The sprite you should think of like a puppet, controlled by the body.